# Dynamics365 details master pattern, always loading first record, how to tell when the new button is pressed?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations

Using the Details Master pattern. When the form initially loads it shows a grid. When clicking on the grid the details are displayed, and is working perfectly fine. The issue with this design pattern is the first record is always loaded so when I look at the cursor the first record is showing.

I'm populating a two list view controls through code (one is available items and the second is selected with buttons to move the items back and forth between the controls) and my issue is when I press "New" the detail page is displayed but the list view is populated for the first record selected. I need a way to know when "New" is pressed I can clear out the list view selected control and just populate the available values.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you add a screenshot? Also take a look at the `OnCreating` event of the data source, that should be triggered by the "New" button.

Comment: I looked into the OnCreating as well and no luck, but I ended going a different direction and creating my own "New" button that calls a menu item to call a form as a popup similar to how the form when entering a new customer works. Then I turned off the "New" button and now my code works fine without have to deal with the one screen containing both forms logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended going a different direction and creating my own "New" button that calls a menu item to call a new form as a popup similar to how the form when entering a new customer works. Then I turned off the "New" button and now my code works fine without have to deal with the one screen containing both forms logic.